# Arithmetic operation on exponential values

Tags: javascript

Is there any limit(minimum value) for arithmetic(+, -) operation on exponential values? I need to perform arithmetic operation with exponential values, while performing addition on certain exponential values, the operation is not performed. Consider the following example,

```
  var a=1.797693134862314e+308,
      q =5e+291;
  q=a+q;
  if(a!= q)
  alert("Value has changed");
```

In this i have used the alert box for ensuring the operation is performed or not,since it is larger value. In the above mentioned values the addition operation is not performed, when the value for "q" variable is changed to "5e+292" the operation will be performed.

Here is the fiddle link:

[Sample working](https://jsfiddle.net/gt9fwnr5/2/)

[Sample not working](https://jsfiddle.net/gt9fwnr5/3/)

I need to know is there any minimum values for arithmetic(+,-) operation for exponential values. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks,

Dharani.

Comment: Are you interested in Java or Javascript? They're different languages. It's not clear what JQuery has to do with this, either... the more specific you can be, the easier it will be to help you. (I suspect you only want the `javascript` tag.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet,sorry for the inconvinence,  I am in need of Javascript only.

Answer (score 1):

Double can only represent numbers to a certain precision. In Java, the next number representable after `1.797693134862314e+308` can be found by:

```
double nextAfter = Math.nextAfter(1.797693134862314e+308, 1.0);
```

which is

```
1.7976931348623137E308
```

i.e. they only differ by 3 at the 17th significant figure.

In other words, if you try to add a number which only affects the `(308-291+1)=`18th significant figure in the larger operand, `double` simply can't represent the difference, so they appear to be the same.

Now, your question is (now) about Javascript, but Javascript floats are IEEE754 64 bit floating point numbers, just like Java doubles. As such, there is no difference in the precision which can be represented.

Comment: The question has been edited to include javascript only.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal edited to point out there is no difference in what can be represented in JS floats and Java doubles.

Comment: If I may suggest, could you reword this question as the answer and downvotes on question makes me feel the question is asked in opposition to SO standards but is actually a valid question?